# Excel 2010 Array Formula (CSE) Dynamic cell range/reference; index? offset?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, array

This might be an easy question to some but I am completely lost so I would really appreciate any help out there!

```
        A      
  1    10
  2    20
  3    30
  4    40
  5    50
  6    60
  7    70
  8    80
  9    90
 10   100
```

Of course my actual work spreadsheet is a lot more complicated than the chart above but the logic I am trying to figure out is this (using array formula):

=SUM(IF(LEN(A1:A3,A8:A10)>0,1)) Control+Shift+Enter I can an error--- I want to write a cell range/reference that **completely ignores** A4:A7 (40, 50, 60, 70). (This comma is not working when it comes to combining 2 cell ranges that are split.)

**Can someone please help me write a cell range/reference that skips the mid-section of the chart! I feel like using OFFSET or INDEX can somehow accommodate the need but I am so lost.**

Comment: @Clif Not sure what you mean by "the format of the data" but basically I want the formula above to ignore A4:A7 completely. Right now I don't know how to write the cell range that will go from A1:A10 but remove A4:A7 in between. The comma doesn't work in this case so... would you happen to know a way?

Comment: @Clif Oh I see yea those asterisks are there just for viewing convenience. I should remove them to mitigate any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer as it is not an array formula, and I haven't come up with one, but it may give you some ideas about how to go about this. Paste `=IF(AND(MOD(ROW(),7)>=1,MOD(ROW(),7)<=3),INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),"")` in B1 and copy down to B10. The sum of column B is now what you want, although I realize it is not the way you wanted to get it. Perhaps there will be someone that will see this and know how to incorporate it into an array formula.

Comment: @Clif Thanks for the idea - I'll definitely incorporate your suggestion. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! Here is the formula:`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A1:A10),7)>=1)*--(MOD(ROW(A1:A10),7)<=3)*A1:A10)` The rational goes along with what you saw when you pasted the formula in my comment to the range B1:B10. Since this is a SUMPRODUCT function you can just press `ENTER`.

Comment: Clif, your formula worked thank you so much! If I may ask a similar question, do you know a way to simply connect 2 non-contiguous ranges? E.g. Connect A1:A3 and A8:A10 (skipping A4:A7)??

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the acceptance. I don't think that there is a simple way that will work with non-contiguous ranges, which is kind of reinforced by the number of people who looked at your post. I think that if there was a simple way someone would have given that answer by now. However someone may yet educate both of us. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Some functions will allow you to use non-contiguous ranges, but typically not array formulas unless you use another criteria (like row number) to explicitly exclude some rows.

With the formula you show in the question, i.e.

`=SUM(IF(LEN(A1:A3,A8:A10)>0,1))`

That, presumably, is designed to count non-blank cells in the specified ranges - if that's all you want to do then perhaps use `COUNTA` - that will count non-blank cells......and you can apply it to non-contiguous ranges, e.g.

`=COUNTA(A1:A3,A8:A10)`

Note that `COUNTA` will also count cells which are populated with a "formula blank".

If that doesn't do what you want then please explain more fully the calculation you want to do

Comment: Barry, the question and the example formula was ultimately used to ask for this question: Is there a way to simply connect 2 non-contiguous ranges? E.g. Connect A1:A3 and A8:A10 (skipping A4:A7)?? Sorry if I caused you any confusion but would you happen to know a way?